# Trades vs Cancel orders

Tags: high-frequency

In case of designing high frequency algorithms, do people treat all changes in the mid price similarly. What  I mean is, if there is a change in the mid price due to a trade or there is a change in the mid price due to an order being cancelled, are these two events the same?

I understand that this is depended on the Algorithm and how i choose to treat it, I was wondering if someone can give me their two cents based on their experience.

Comment: Your question is very similar to this one: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/43481/modelling-hft-data

Comment: @wildbunny  yes, it is similar, though not same.